# Hiding and Showing Columns Based on Value in Cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm looking to create a script that hides/shows columns based off of a value in a particular cell, but I know absolutely nothing about coding. I've tried to adapt code from other answers on the site but have been unsuccessful, and don't know enough about coding to know why.

Here's what I want to accomplish:
If the value in A3 is 1, show columns C-E, hide columns F-AF;
If the value in A3 is 2, show columns C-H, hide columns I-AF;
If the value in A3 is 3, show columns C-K, hide columns L-AF
And so on in increments of 3 columns until:
If the value in A3 is 10, show columns C-AF

Here is what I was able to try and piece together. I'm sure it's very wrong:

```
function HideSelectedBlocks() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("Contract");
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var A3=sh.getRange("A3").getValue();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
    var column=i+1;
    switch(A3)
    {
      case '1':
        if(column>=C && column<=E){sh.showColumns(column);}
        if(column>=F && column<=AF){sh.hideColumns(column);}
        break;
      case '2':
        if(column>=C && column<=H){sh.showColumns(column);}
        if(column>=I && column<=AF){sh.hideColumns(column);}
        break;
        case '3':
        if(column>=C && column<=K){sh.showColumns(column);}
        if(column>=L && column<=AF){sh.hideColumns(column);}
        break;
        case '4':
        if(column>=C && column<=N){sh.showColumns(column);}
        if(column>=O && column<=AF){sh.hideColumns(column);}
        break;
        case '5':
        if(column>=C && column<=Q){sh.showColumns(column);}
        if(column>=R && column<=AF){sh.hideColumns(column);}
        break;
        case '6':
        if(column>=C && column<=T){sh.showColumns(column);}
        if(column>=U && column<=AF){sh.hideColumns(column);}
        break;
        case '7':
        if(column>=C && column<=W){sh.showColumns(column);}
        if(column>=X && column<=AF){sh.hideColumns(column);}
        break;
        case '8':
        if(column>=C && column<=Z){sh.showColumns(column);}
        if(column>=AA && column<=AF){sh.hideColumns(column);}
        break;
        case '9':
        if(column>=C && column<=AC){sh.showColumns(column);}
        if(column>=AD && column<=AF){sh.hideColumns(column);}
        break;
        case '10':
        if(column>=C && column<=AF){sh.showColumns(column);}
        break;
      default:
    }
  }
}
```

I then also need two more that do essentially the same thing:
If the value in A5 is 1, show columns AH-AJ, hide columns AK-BK
continuing with increments of 3 columns until:
If the value in A5 is 10, show columns AH-BK
and
If the value in A7 is 1, show columns BM-BO, hide columns BP-CP
continuing with increments of 3 columns until:
If the value in A7 is 10, show columns BM-CP

Here is an example document, in case it is useful: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RPWjc-3jkCqVcRapinDuCS7kghaI8YYP45I2O6JVU-s/edit?usp=sharing
I can also build the scripts pulling from A5 and A7 as long as I know what values in the script to change. I also don't know if this is something included in the script, or if it needs to be implemented elsewhere, but I would love the script to run on an edit of the appropriate cell (i.e. A5 for the first one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Suggestion

Perhaps you can try this tweaked script below that uses a [JSON object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp) variable called `columns` to predefine which columns are to be hidden based on the selected value on the `A3` cell:

### Tweaked Script

```
function HideSelectedBlocks() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Contract");
  var A3 = sheet.getRange("A3").getValue();
  var columns = [
  {
    "Selection": 1,
    "StartCol": sheet.getRange("F:F").getColumn(),
    "EndCol": (32 - sheet.getRange("F:F").getColumn())+1
  },
  {
    "Selection": 2,
    "StartCol": sheet.getRange("I:I").getColumn(),
    "EndCol": (32 - sheet.getRange("I:I").getColumn())+1
  },
  {
    "Selection": 3,
    "StartCol": sheet.getRange("L:L").getColumn(),
    "EndCol": (32 - sheet.getRange("L:L").getColumn())+1
  },
  {
    "Selection": 4,
    "StartCol": sheet.getRange("O:O").getColumn(),
    "EndCol": (32 - sheet.getRange("O:O").getColumn())+1
  },
  {
    "Selection": 5,
    "StartCol": sheet.getRange("R:R").getColumn(),
    "EndCol": (32 - sheet.getRange("R:R").getColumn())+1
  },
  {
    "Selection": 6,
    "StartCol": sheet.getRange("U:U").getColumn(),
    "EndCol": (32 - sheet.getRange("U:U").getColumn())+1
  },
  {
    "Selection": 7,
    "StartCol": sheet.getRange("X:X").getColumn(),
    "EndCol": (32 - sheet.getRange("X:X").getColumn())+1
  },
  {
    "Selection": 8,
    "StartCol": sheet.getRange("AA:AA").getColumn(),
    "EndCol": (32 - sheet.getRange("AA:AA").getColumn())+1
  },
  {
    "Selection": 9,
    "StartCol": sheet.getRange("AD:AD").getColumn(),
    "EndCol": (32 - sheet.getRange("AD:AD").getColumn())+1
  }
];

  for(x=0; x <columns.length; x++){
    if(A3 == 10) return; //Nothing will be hidden when 10 is selected on A3
    if(columns[x].Selection == A3){
      sheet.showColumns(1, 32); //Removes previously hidden columns
      sheet.hideColumns(columns[x].StartCol, columns[x].EndCol); //Sets new hidden column
    }
  }
}
```

### ***[UPDATE]***

## To do the same process on the `Second half assignments` & so on and so forth, follow this sample:

> E.g. to create a separate function for the second half (read the
> `//` comments) :

```
function hideSecondHalf(){
  //The end column is "BK" or # 63 for the second half
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Contract");
  var A5 = sheet.getRange("A5").getValue();
  //On your columns variable per 'Selection', just put #63 on each 'EndCol' & change the corresponding StartCol range as seen below:
  var columns = [
    {
      "Selection": 1,
      "StartCol": sheet.getRange("AK:AK").getColumn(),
      "EndCol": (63 - sheet.getRange("AK:AK").getColumn())+1
    },
    {
      "Selection": 2,
      "StartCol": sheet.getRange("AN:AN").getColumn(),
      "EndCol": (63 - sheet.getRange("AN:AN").getColumn())+1
    },
    {
      "Selection": 3,
      "StartCol": sheet.getRange("AQ:AQ").getColumn(),
      "EndCol": (63 - sheet.getRange("AQ:AQ").getColumn())+1
    },
    {
      "Selection": 4,
      "StartCol": sheet.getRange("AT:AT").getColumn(),
      "EndCol": (63 - sheet.getRange("AT:AT").getColumn())+1
    },
    {
      "Selection": 5,
      "StartCol": sheet.getRange("AW:AW").getColumn(),
      "EndCol": (63 - sheet.getRange("AW:AW").getColumn())+1
    },
    {
      "Selection": 6,
      "StartCol": sheet.getRange("AZ:AZ").getColumn(),
      "EndCol": (63 - sheet.getRange("AZ:AZ").getColumn())+1
    },
    {
      "Selection": 7,
      "StartCol": sheet.getRange("BC:BC").getColumn(),
      "EndCol": (63 - sheet.getRange("BC:BC").getColumn())+1
    },
    {
      "Selection": 8,
      "StartCol": sheet.getRange("BF:BF").getColumn(),
      "EndCol": (63 - sheet.getRange("BF:BF").getColumn())+1
    },
    {
      "Selection": 9,
      "StartCol": sheet.getRange("BI:BI").getColumn(),
      "EndCol": (63 - sheet.getRange("BI:BI").getColumn())+1
    }
  ];
  for(x=0; x <columns.length; x++){
    if(A5 == 10 || A5 == "") return; //Nothing will be hidden when 10 is selected on A5 or A5 is empty
    if(columns[x].Selection == A5){
      sheet.showColumns(34, 63); //Removes previously hidden columns starting from Column AG or #34 to BK or #63
      sheet.hideColumns(columns[x].StartCol, columns[x].EndCol); //Sets new hidden column
    }
  }
}
```

### Sample Demonstration:

- **Sample Sheet:**

> [image]

- **Say number `2` is selected on cell `A3`. After running the script function:**

> [image]

- **Then, say number `3` is selected. After running the script:**

> [image]

## ***[UPDATE]***

- On second half assignment `hideSecondHalf` function, say `2` was selected on cell `A5`:

> [image]

Comment: @Joel S. Feel free to comment in case I have misunderstood your goal.

Comment: That works really well for the first set. I was hoping I'd be able to accomplish the same thing for the Second Half Assignments and the Final Exams. So basically I would love to accomplish the same thing, but when a value is in A5, it ignores all columns up to AG, and starts revealing/hiding columns from there. I don't know how doable that is, so I can make it work using this script if it can't be done otherwise.Thank you so much for your solution, it works beautifully for the first part

Comment: @JoelS. I see. To accomplish the same thing for the Second Half & possibly the Final assignments, there's actually pattern on the script, just create a separate function for each of the `assignments`. I have added a separate function for `Second Half Assignment` on my answer as a sample guide for you (it contains some comments that you can read). I hope it helps.

Comment: @JoelS.  You may also want to click the accept/up-vote button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be answered & they'll easily see this post on their searches.

Comment: That's excellent, thank you so much, and thanks for taking the time to explain what each section meant, I have a much greater grasp of what is happening in that code and how to adapt it!